# KDevelop automatically inserts a space after # in #include <file.h>

Tags: c++, kdevelop

I simply want to include a C++ header file in KDevelop by writing

```
#include <file.h>
```

However, KDevelop automatically corrects the above statement to

```
# include <file.h>
```

I have not been able to figure out where I can change this. I want the first version, such that my files are similar to the other files in the project I am working on.

The file is type set correctly as a C++ file. I think the reason for the extra space is that KDevelop wants to indent the line because it is inside a conditional, i.e. a include guard as given below:

```
#ifndef THIS_FILE_H
#define THIS_FILE_H

// THIS_FILE_H
#endif
```

KDevelop also wants to indent the `#define THIS_FILE_H` line.

I have tried created my own indentation style by going to the **Settings -> Customize KDevelop** menu item, and then clicking on **Source Formatter** on the left. When defining the formatting style, I have disabled the indentation of *preprocessor directives*, nevertheless, it has no effect on the indentation of the `#include` and `#define` inside the include guard.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't matter at least.

Comment: It matters enough to break the SO code highlighting. I have no idea how this could happen and go unnoticed tbh. KDevelop is not that small from what I heard.

Comment: That's right, but it has been annoying me for quite some time now, so figured somebody might know how to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Is the file type set correctly?  Maybe KDevelop thinks you're writing in a language that uses the `#` character as a start of a comment in the code (e.g. Python, Perl, shell).

Comment: Maybe it is using a C style indenting rules, since the ".h" usually indicates a C language header.

Comment: I believe I figured out what is causing it, but still cannot change the behaviour. See edited question above.

Comment: This should have something to do with Kate part of KDevelop. Play around with options in `Configure Editor` menu, because i don't see this behavior.

Comment: I use KDevelop 4.7.3 every day and haven't ever seen this.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I think they follow certain code styling where common directives would have one or more spaces and  ` #if #else #endif` having  none at start (but can be idented). SO it's more of misfeature because "developer thought it should be default"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite old but here is my advice, for future reference.

Go to `Settings -> Configure KDevelop -> Code Formatter`.

There you'll be able to see a dropdown the language you want KDevelop to format (C, C++, C#, Java, and whatever), the formatter ("Artistic Style" or "Custom Script Formatter") and a list of possible predefined styles plus buttons to customise your own.

Check whether you have selected one suitable predefined and try a few ones to see what happens.

KDevelop should stop adding the extra space after `# include` after this.

**Question:** does your KDevelop also adds a space after a `#define` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem. So, I uninstall `kate`, then remove all config files in home directory whose name contains `kate`. Then I opened kdevelop and found nothing change. At last, `Kdevelop->Settings->Open/Save->Modes&Filetypes`, select `Sources/C++` and `Sources/C`, change it to `None`, restart kdevelop. OMG, finally, the world is peace.

To conclude, the `Sources Modes&Filetypes` occur the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic spaces appear to be caused by the indentation mode, which (in KDevelop 4.7.1) you can switch for the current file via `Editor -> Tools -> Indentation`. If indentation is set to `C++/boost Style`, you'll get those weird automatic spaces while typing; while in mode `Normal` you only get the usual indentation at beginning of line.

The default indentation mode can be set in `Settings -> Configure Editor -> Open/Save -> Modes & Filetypes`. For each Filetype (eg. `Sources/C`, `Sources/C++`, `Sources/C++11`, `Sources/C++11/Qt4`) the Indentation Mode can be set independently.

KDevelop appears to remember the setting for files you have opened once; so for these files the new configuration settings have no effect. I don't know how to make KDevelop forget these per-file settings.